# What is the origin of the term magma?

Tags: ho.history-overview, abstract-algebra, etymology, magmas

Wikipedia credits Bourbaki with coining it, but doesn't provide a source. Does anyone happen to know the motivation for using this term?

Comment: One theory I've seen is that the term comes from the (perceived) primordial, amorphous nature of molten rock

Comment: A similar thing was asked here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63210/etymology-of-magma-in-abstract-algebra 

Comment: My answer seems to agree with the stack exchange one. 

Comment: So it isn't a typo for gamma?  Gerhard "Commutative Algebra Is For Lysdexics" Paseman, 2012.07.25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second definition in http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/francais/magma/48543 would seem to answer your question and agrees with the wiki page.

Update:  here is what the link said to avoid broken links as YCor pointed out.

> magma
>   nom masculin
>   (latin magma, résidu, du grec magma)
>
> Mélange formant une masse pâteuse, épaisse : Magma informe.
>
> Mélange confus, inextricable de choses abstraites  : Ces propositions constituent un magma incohérent.
>
> Matériau constitué de liquide et de cristaux en proportions variables, qui se forme à l'intérieur de la Terre et qui, en refroidissant, forme une roche.

Comment: Interesting that the French use the word in several ways, but English has only the one meaning, the geological.

Comment: This definitely seems like the most likely explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The link is broken. Possibly it matches with http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/magma/48543, but copying the contents would prevent the answer become obsolete when the Larousse page is edited.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia also says that "magma" is used by Serre in his book *Lie algebras and lie groups: 1964 Lectures given at Harvard University*.  This seems to be the case (at least for the 1992 Springer reprint that I have access to.)  Is this the earliest use in print of "magma" in this sense?

Comment: I will add a link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magma_(algebra)&oldid=834331021) of the [Wikipedia article in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)). (Just in case it changes in the future.)

Comment: The first edition of Bourbaki's Algèbre Chapitre 1 dates back to 1942, see http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Gerard.Eguether/archives/elements.pdf

Comment: There was no mention of magma in that first edition. The first time magma is mentioned is in the Nouvelle Édition, published in 1970.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg. Thanks for pointing this out (I didn't have the first edition to check it). This is consistent with the Bourbaki archives http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/  not mentioning "magma" either.

Comment: You are welcome, cher @François Brunault.